# C# MEF Set Property/Property Injection

Tags: .net-4.0, mef

Is there any way to get it work using Microsoft Extensibility Framework(MEF)

Lets say i have interface

```
public interface IApplicationSettings
{
   string SettingOne { get; }
}
```

Class which implementing this interface

```
[Export(typeof(IApplicationSettings))]
public class ApplicationSettings : IApplicationSettings
{ 
   public string SettingOne
   {
       get
       {
           return "AAA";
       }        
    }
}
```

Class which containg my interface as a property

```
public class IoCConstructorMef
{
    [Import("ApplicationSettings", typeof(IApplicationSettings))]
    public IApplicationSettings ApplicationSettings { get; set; }
}
```

then i am expecting that my property going to be injected here:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     IoCConstructorMef cm = new IoCConstructorMef();
     //cm.ApplicationSettings - is null

 }
```

Looks like there no injection happens in this case.

Am i missed something or did something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to let the `CompositionContainer` create an object for you for its imports to be satisfied.  Add an `ExportAttribute` to `IoCConstructorMef`, create a container, and call `container.GetExportedValue<IoCConstructorMef>()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to let MEF construct your IoCConstructorMef cm. otherwise the import will not happen.